# Error "subscript of pointer to function type 'int *(int)'"

Tags: c++, root-framework

I am writing a code to find a cluster, I am using "cern root" to plot graphs,
the data is saved in ".root" file, but the code is written in c++. The data is saved as a 2D histogram. The logic of the code is once I find a bin with some signal in it, I find the neighbours around it (8 bins), then I tag the bin and increase the cluster size, and then do the same for the neighbour. I started by making a fiction to find the neighbour (the function returns an array with the x coordinate and another finds the y coordinate)

```
int* neighbour_function_i(int i){   
int* neighbour_i = new int[8];   // Pointer to int, initialize to nothing.
neighbour_i[0] = {i-1}, neighbour_i[1] = {i}, neighbour_i[2] = {i+1}, neighbour_i[3] = {i-1}, neighbour_i[4] = {i+1}, neighbour_i[5] = {i-1}, neighbour_i[6] = {i}, neighbour_i[7] = {i+1};
return neighbour_i; //check if this works
}
```

the code that finds the cluster is as below

```
    int* temp_neighbour_i = NULL;
    int* temp_neightbour_j = NULL;
    int uncheckedneighbours, total_neighbours;
    int clsize = 0;
    int temp_i,temp_j;

  for(int i = 0; i < NPIXAX; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < NPIXAY; j++){
        clsize = 0;
        if(h->GetBinContent(i + 1, j + 1) - ped[i][j] > 0 && pedbf[i][j] == 0){//condition to find a cluster
           pedbf[i][j] = 1; //Tag arry
           clsize = 1;
           uncheckedneighbours = 8;
           total_neighbours = uncheckedneighbours;
           int* neighbour_i = neighbour_function_i[i];//the error is here
           int* neighbour_j = neighbour_function_j[j];//the error is here
           while(uncheckedneighbours != 0){
              for(int n = 0; n < total_neighbours; n++){
                temp_i = neighbour_i[n];//Temp int for coordienate 
                temp_j = neighbour_j[n];//Temp int for coordinate
                if(h->GetBinContent(temp_i, temp_j) - ped[temp_i][temp_j] > 0 && pedbf[temp_i][temp_j] == 0){//condition to find a cluster
                    pedbf[temp_i][temp_j] = 1;
                    int* new_neighbour_i = neighbour_function_i[temp_i];//the error is here
                    int* new_neighbour_j = neighbour_function_j[temp_j];//the error is here
                    uncheckedneighbours += 8;
                    total_neighbours += 8; 
                    int* temp_neighbour_i = new int[clsize * 8];
                    int* temp_neighbour_j = new int[clsize * 8];
                    clsize++;
                    temp_neighbour_i[n] = neighbour_i[n];//moving data to chnage the size of neighbour/i array
                    temp_neighbour_j[n] = neighbour_j[n];//moving data to change the size of neighbour_j array
                    delete[] neighbour_i;//deallocate neighbour
                    delete[] neighbour_j;//deallocate neighbour
                    int *neighbour_i = new int[clsize * 8]; //re-allocate the size of neighbour with size = size(clsize *8)
                    int *neighbour_j = new int[clsize * 8]; //re-allocate the size of neighbour with size = size(clsize *8)
                    for(int x = 0; x < (clsize - 1) * 8; x++){ //neighbour = temp_neighbour + new_neighbour
                        neighbour_i[x] = temp_neighbour_i[x]; 
                        neighbour_j[x] = temp_neighbour_j[x]; 
                    }
                    for(int x = (clsize - 1)*8; x < clsize * 8; x++){
                        neighbour_i[x] = new_neighbour_i[x];
                        neighbour_j[x] = new_neighbour_j[x];
                    }
                    delete[]temp_neighbour_i; //dealocate temp and new
                    delete[]temp_neighbour_j; //dealocate temp and new
                    delete[]new_neighbour_i; //dealocate temp and new
                    delete[]new_neighbour_j; //dealocate temp and new
                }
                uncheckedneighbours--;
              }
           }
        //if(clsize != 0){;//output to file cluseter size, i, j
        //}
        }
    }
 }
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error "subscript of pointer to function type 'int *(int)'"?

Comment: How about `std::array<int, 8> neighbour_function_i(int i){  return {{i-1, i, i+1, i-1, i+1, i-1, i, i+1}};}
`? and get rid of (manual) allocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe question should be closed as typo, but a function gets called like this:

```
int* neighbour_i = neighbour_function_i(i);
```

Not like this:

```
int* neighbour_i = neighbour_function_i[i];
```

Comment: @Tman I am sure, that this isn't the only problem in your code example. It will compile, but I see a lot of problems, which could lead to runtime errors

Comment: as @Jarod42 suggested, use c++ std containers, like std::array or std::vector. Then you don#T have to manually manage the memory

Comment: thank you for your comments, I would appreciate if you could point out the problems

Comment: The code example is to big and unmanageable to pinpoint the exact errors. I would start refactoring the code with exchanging old c-style arrays [] with either std::array or std::vector.